# Ext JS: Unable to place grid panel in a container

Tags: extjs

I am unable to place a grid - panel within a container. Here is my layout example. Please ignore any opening or close braces, I want to give a high level layout structure that I have designed.

Problem: Here, in the example i.e., third container I am unable place a panel and a grid in it. When i remove the grid, the layout works fine, when i place the grid then all the layout seems blank and I don't see other components as well, also I am not getting any console errors. I have tried even giving fixed width and heights for the containers. Issue is with the layout and the display of components.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

```
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
items: [{
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'vbox',
            items: [{
               xtype: 'container',
               layout: 'hbox',
               items: [{-----}]
            },{
               xtype: 'container',
               layout: 'hbox',
               items: {
                       xtype: 'panel',
                       title: 'Hours of Operation',
                        itemId: 'hoursOfOperationPanel',
                        items: {
                           xtype: 'grid',
                           store: hoursStore,
                        }
                 },
            },{
               xtype: 'container',
               layout: 'hbox',
               items: [{-----}]               
            }]
      }]
```

Comment: Which error occur? It will be good if you share some sample code in fiddle

Comment: any error msg? and i hope you have set all necessary configs for the grids. like columns etc.

Comment: @Tejas I am not getting any console errors, the screen does not show any components.

Comment: @Snehal Dangroshiya I had given columns and I have so many child components which i did not list all of them and given high level layout...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using containers with in a container, you can try as mentioned below by including items in a container and define them a default layout. You can clearly find elements at one level and their corresponding child elements.

```
Ext.apply(me, {
        items: [{
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'vbox',
            defaults: {
                layout: 'hbox',
                flex: 1,
                width: '100%',
                defaults: {
                    height: '100%'
                }
            },
            items: [{
                items: [{

                }]
            },{
                items: [{

                }]
            }]
        }],
});
```

Comment: Thanks for providing me another way of doing things using items within a container and it resolved my issue... Thanks a ton once again...

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is overnesting and/or wrong use of layouts. Just from the example you have given above, this would be more appropriate:

```
// classic
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
items: [{
  xtype: 'container',
  layout: 'vbox',
  items: [{
    xtype: 'container',
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [{-----}]
  },{
    xtype: 'grid',
    title: 'Hours of Operation',
    itemId: 'hoursOfOperationPanel',
    store: hoursStore // don't set this to an instance
  },{
    xtype: 'container',
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [{-----}]
  }]
}]

// modern
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
items: [{
  xtype: 'container',
  layout: 'vbox',
  items: [{
    xtype: 'container',
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [{-----}]
  },{
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'Hours of Operation',
    itemId: 'hoursOfOperationPanel',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
      xtype: 'grid',
      store: hoursStore // don't set this to an instance
    }]
  },{
    xtype: 'container',
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [{-----}]
  }]
}]
```

The reason the modern toolkit version needs to be wrapped in a panel is for the title. Modern's grid is not a panel and therefor doesn't get a title so you can either nest in a panel (with fit layout) or give the grid a docked titlebar.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out to me and taking your time to check this.... I have tried to use the layout:'fit' but no luck... Is there a way i can provide screen shot here in stack overflow apart from writing code?

Comment: That’s going to mean there is another problem up stream. Would have to know more about your app and it’s stricture but from the looks of it, you see you be using box layouts and nesting a lot without knowing what you’re doing.

Comment: I know what I am doing, its screen of more elements, how would you do without nesting more elements in a parent child architecture, they are not siblings to leave them in different files and its an enterprise application....I can't type everything here 500 lines of code that is the reason i have given a high level skeleton layout. Thanks for your time, i can sort it out by myself.

Comment: You cannot say this question as not useful and reduce other's reputations by simply given unnecessary votes...there are so many good people out there who will help me, you cannot vote and discourage others as if you have a good reputation...

Comment: Sorry I thought it was you, my apologies... I was upset when you mentioned you don't know what you doing... Thanks for your time on this...